# SQL переменные?

Tags: sql

Есть такой *Sql* запрос:

```
 "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c LEFT JOIN " 
 . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) LEFT JOIN "
 . DB_PREFIX . "category_to_store c2s ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) 
 WHERE c.parent_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "' AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') 
 . "' AND c2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') 
 . "'  AND c.status = '1' ORDER BY c.sort_order, LCASE(cd.name)"
```

Непонятно, что такое c, cd и c2s? Это переменные в *Sql* или я что-то не понимаю?

P.S. Запрос взят из *Opencart*.

Comment: [Alias_(SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_\(SQL\))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется `alias` (псевдоним). Он, так скажем, указывает на ту таблицу, с названием которой рядом написан (инициализирован).

То есть в итоге можно не писать каждый раз `category_description`, а достаточно писать псевдоним `cd`. Очень удобно, когда нужно в запросе перечислить много полей или джойнов, вложенных запросов и вместо гигантских запросов с названием таблиц типа `my_super_mega_cool_table_name_that_i_can_imagine` писать просто `mt` к примеру.

То есть минимум: для повышения читаемости запросов,  для многократного использования одной и той же таблицы в одном запросе, для именования подзапросов (в MySQL это обязательно, в отличие от других СУБД).

Пример с одним простым запросом

```
SELECT  mt.`name`, mt.`description`, mt.`text`,
        dl.`class`, dl.`sex`
FROM `my_super_mega_cool_table_name_that_i_can_imagine`  mt
LEFT JOIN `what_is_the_damn_long_name_of_the_table`  dl
ON mt.`id` = dl.`id`
WHERE mt.`id` = 666
```

для сравнения он же без псевдонимов

```
SELECT  my_super_mega_cool_table_name_that_i_can_imagine.`name`, my_super_mega_cool_table_name_that_i_can_imagine.`description`, my_super_mega_cool_table_name_that_i_can_imagine.`text`,
        what_is_the_damn_long_name_of_the_table.`class`, what_is_the_damn_long_name_of_the_table.`sex`
FROM `my_super_mega_cool_table_name_that_i_can_imagine` 
LEFT JOIN `what_is_the_damn_long_name_of_the_table`  
ON my_super_mega_cool_table_name_that_i_can_imagine.`id` = what_is_the_damn_long_name_of_the_table.`id`
WHERE my_super_mega_cool_table_name_that_i_can_imagine.`id` = 666
```

Comment: Его всегда справа нужно писать?

Comment: @Shillkas справа от названия таблицы, либо справа от вложенного запроса.. но при перечислении таблиц он будет слева..... то есть есть к примеру `mt.col1, mt.col2` и т.д.

Comment: Ага, понял, в остальных случаях его справа пишут без какого-либо оператора?

Comment: Можно ли задать имя псевдониму как where например? Или псевдонимы не должны иметь имя как у других операторов?

Comment: @Shillkas ` справа пишут без какого-либо оператора? ` - обычно хватает и так. Хотя для именования подзапросов ЕМНИП можно писать  `as SOM_ALIAS`..... `Можно ли задать имя псевдониму как where например?` - не понял. оператору? нет. только  наименованием таблиц, подзапросов  и выбираемым значениям, например `SELECT my_table.my_column as SUPER`...........`псевдонимы не должны иметь имя как у других операторов?` - конечно же не должны)

Comment: А все, понял, спасибо за ответ

Comment: результирующий набор будет в себе содержать 5 колонок, да. сами таблицы `my_super_mega_cool_table_name_that_i_can_imagine` и `what_is_the_damn_long_name_of_the_table могут` содержать гораздо больше полей, но я, например, захотел в результате выбрать 5. А представь если бы надо было вернуть 20 колонок и все это без псевдонима))

Comment: В начале запроса используется псевдоним который еще как бы не объявлен, я имею ввиду откуда sql исполнитель должен узнать что такое mt в select, ведь строчка `my_super_mega_cool_table_name_that_i_can_imagine`  mt находится дальше, или это в порядке нормы?

Comment: @Shillkas как и везде в языках есть парсеры и анализаторы. Внутри механизм в начале разбирает запрос на части, производит некие оптимизации и сопоставления и потом делает то, что его попросили. Он не тупо считывает инструкции сверху вниз.